# How to print contents in columns if contents is same value, just print once. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset like this, I want to print contents in 'Protocol' columns.

```
pcap_df = pd.read_csv('pcap.csv')
pcap_df.head(10)

    No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
0   1   0.000000    172.253.118.188 192.168.1.34    TLSv1.2 1334    Application Data
1   2   0.000272    172.253.118.188 192.168.1.34    TLSv1.2 788 Application Data
2   3   0.000309    192.168.1.34    172.253.118.188 TCP 54  43242 > 5228 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2015 Win=64400 ...
3   4   0.042950    192.168.1.34    74.125.24.136   QUIC    1292    Initial, DCID=be8c031f7abfaec5, PKN: 1, PING, ...
4   5   0.043241    192.168.1.34    74.125.24.136   QUIC    120 0-RTT, DCID=be8c031f7abfaec5
5   6   0.043469    192.168.1.34    74.125.24.136   QUIC    1288    0-RTT, DCID=be8c031f7abfaec5
6   7   0.043991    192.168.1.34    74.125.24.136   QUIC    169 0-RTT, DCID=be8c031f7abfaec5
7   8   0.053225    192.168.1.34    74.125.130.132  TCP 55  59756 > 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64361 Len=...
8   9   0.065535    74.125.24.136   192.168.1.34    QUIC    1292    Protected Payload (KP0)
9   10  0.065535    74.125.24.136   192.168.1.34    QUIC    824 Protected Payload (KP0)
```

and if I run

```
pcap_df['Protocol']
```

result

```
0       TLSv1.2
1       TLSv1.2
2           TCP
3          QUIC
4          QUIC
         ...   
8324    TLSv1.3
8325    TLSv1.3
8326        TCP
8327        TCP
8328        TCP
```

And I want output like this.

```
TLSv1.2
TCP
QUIC
TLSv1.3
```

I've been searching for solution within 3 days, but still, not get right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `df.unique()`. That will give an array that contains each unique value. Then a little playing for exactly how you want to display.

```py
pcap_df['Protocol'].unique()
```

Then you can print it, convert to a list and print, make a loop to print each value on a line, etc etc

Comment: Ah thankyou, problem solved. I'm sorry I didn't read all Pandas document.